# Como centrar un archivo json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Necesito centrar un archivo json.Soy muy principiante.Ya probre con center pero no me funciona.

{ "1": "HTML - CSS",
"2": "JavaScript",
"3": "GitHub - GitHub Desktop",
"4": "Visual Studio Code", "5": "JQuery",
"6": "Telerik - Kendo UI", "7": "Angular - Kendo UI", "8": "VUE - Kendo UI", "9": "REACT - Kendo UI"}

Leer JSon  
 
$.getJSON("cache/test.json", function( data ) { var items = []; $.each( data, function( key, val ) { items.push( "" + val + "" ); }); $( "", { "class": "my-new-list", html: items.join( "" ) }).appendTo( "body" ); });

Siempre me queda de un lado izquierdo.

Comment: Hola @Alejandra Adalid, edite tu pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/243839 para mostrar un fragmento de código, no entiendo a que te refieres con centrarlo, ¿seria como lo hace jsonformatter https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com?

Answer (score 1):

Hola si lo que quieres es presentar el json  en el html centrado al ancho, esto te puede servir:
Cuando tengas el json recorrelo `for(var key in tuJson)` como objeto y ve formando un html en una variable, cuando tengas todo el html entonces por id encuentra el contenedor y inserta|agrega el html, para centrarlo a dicho contenedor agregale estilos para centrarlo  `display: flex; justify-content: center;`

Con JQuery

```js
var jsonData = { "1": "HTML - CSS", "2": "JavaScript", "3": "GitHub - GitHub Desktop", "4": "Visual Studio Code", "5": "JQuery", "6": "Telerik - Kendo UI", "7": "Angular - Kendo UI", "8": "VUE - Kendo UI", "9": "REACT - Kendo UI"};
//al leer el documento
$(document).ready(function () {
var _jsonString = "{"+ '</br>';

// Recorre el json cada llave y valor y damos un salto de linea para el formato.
for(var key in jsonData){
  _jsonString +=key+":"+" "+jsonData[key]+ '</br>';
}
_jsonString +="}"

//Obtenemos por id el contenedor donde se mostrará el json con formato.
$("#show-data").append(_jsonString)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
<div id="show-data" style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center;"></div>
</body>
```

Solo javascript:

```js
var jsonData = { "1": "HTML - CSS", "2": "JavaScript", "3": "GitHub - GitHub Desktop", "4": "Visual Studio Code", "5": "JQuery", "6": "Telerik - Kendo UI", "7": "Angular - Kendo UI", "8": "VUE - Kendo UI", "9": "REACT - Kendo UI"};

var _jsonString = "{"+ '</br>';

// Recorre el json cada llave y valor y damos un salto de linea para el formato.
for(var key in jsonData){
  _jsonString +=key+":"+" "+jsonData[key]+ '</br>';
}
_jsonString +="}"
//Obtenemos por id el contenedor donde se mostrará el json con formato.
document.getElementById('show-data').insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",_jsonString);
```

```html
<body>
<div id="show-data" style="width: 100%; display: flex; justify-content: center;"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Gracias por reponder! Lo voy a probar!